# How do I get info from the stack, using inline assembly, to program in c?

Tags: c, stack, inline, interrupt, volatile

I have a task to do and I'm asking for some help. (on simple c lang')

What I need to do?
I need to check every command on the main c program (using interrupt num 1) and printing a message only if the next command is the same procedure that was sent earlier to the stack, by some other procedure.

What I want to do?
I want to take info from the stack, using inline assembley, and put it on a variable that can be compare on c program itself after returnning to c. (volatile)

This is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void (*FUN_PTR)(void);
void interrupt (*Int1Save) (void); //pointer to interrupt num 1//

volatile FUN_PTR our_func;
char *str2;

void interrupt my_inter (void) //New interrupt//
{volatile FUN_PTR next_command;
asm {   PUSH BP
    MOV BP,SP
    PUSH AX
    PUSH BX
    PUSH ES
    MOV ES,[BP+4]           
    MOV BX,[BP+2] 
    MOV AX,ES:[BX]
    MOV word ptr next_command,AX  
    POP ES
    POP BX
    POP AX
    pop BP}
if (our_func==next_command) printf("procedure %s has been called\n",str2);}

void animate(int *iptr,char str[],void (*funptr)(), char fstr[])
{
str2=fstr;
our_func=funptr;

Int1Save = getvect(1); // save old interrupt//
setvect(1,my_inter); 
    asm {   pushf //TF is ON//
    pop ax
    or ax,100000000B
    push ax
    popf}}

void unanimate()
{asm {  pushf //TF is OFF//
        pop ax
        and ax,1111111011111111B
        push ax
        popf}
setvect (1,Int1Save); //restore old interrupt//}

void main(void)
{int i;
 int f1 = 1;
 int f2 = 1;
 int fibo = 1;

 animate(&fibo, "fibo", sleep, "sleep");
 for(i=0; i < 8; i++)
 {
  sleep(2);
  f1 = f2;
  f2 = fibo;
  fibo = f1 + f2;} // for//
 unanimate();} // main//
```

My question... 
Off course the problem is at "my inter" on the inline assembly. but can't figure it out. 
What am I doing wrong? (please take a look at the code above)
I wanted to save the address of the pointer for the specific procedure (sleep) in the volatile our_func. then take the info (address to each next command) from the stack to volatile next_command and then finaly returnning to c and make the compare each time. If the same value (address) is on both variables then to print a specific message. 
Hope I'm clear..

10x,

Nir B

Comment: I'm afraid your question isn't clear. What do you mean by "check every command"? Every command-line argument? Every function call? Every assembly instruction? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Can't you just use some of the programs that give you the call graph?

Comment: Say we looking at the main...
After calling to procedure "animate" - this procedure will change num 1 interrupt for our use, there's a loop with commands. 
As part of the task I want to check what is the next command to implement (inside the loop)- and if the command is the procedure sent to animate (like sleep for example) I want to print that "command %s (sleep for our example) as been called".

Comment: OK! I GOT THE ANSWER I WANTED: 
    
asm { MOV SI,[BP+18] //Taking the address of each command//
 MOV DI,[BP+20] 
 MOV word ptr next_command+2,DI 
 MOV word ptr next_command,SI}

if ((*our_func)==(*next_command)) //Making the next_command compare//
printf("procedure %s has been called\n",str2);

10x anyway.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>[Answered as a comment by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843044/how-do-i-get-info-from-the-stack-using-inline-assembly-to-program-in-c/24279524#comment22554662_15843044)</sup>

I got the answer I wanted:

```
asm {   MOV SI,[BP+18]  //Taking the address of each command//
        MOV DI,[BP+20]
        MOV word ptr next_command+2,DI
        MOV word ptr next_command,SI}
if ((*our_func)==(*next_command))   //Making the next_command compare//
    printf("procedure %s has been called\n",str2);
```